# remove word if alternative word already in use in excel

Tags: excel

Hi i want to remove word if their is already alternative word used in cell value. For ex:

```
Cell A                              | Cell B
----------------------------------------------------------------
this is my wishes greetings to you | this is my greetings to you
-----------------------------------------------------------------
this is wishes greetings for you   | this is wishes for you
```

so i want to just one word from two (wishes and greetings) in some wishes will remove in some greetings will remove. 
I tried find and replace tool but it was not work as what i want .

Comment: What determines which to use?

Comment: @ScottCraner random or one time each . one time wishes and one time greetings . any way to do this ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do it randomly:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,2),"wishes ","greetings "),"")
```

To do it by row:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHOOSE(MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,2)+1,"wishes ","greetings "),"")
```

The first is volatile as in it will change every time excel re calculates.  The second depends on the row number.

[image]

Comment: thanks again @scott for help .. you are the best .. thanks again